# HTTPS not working when putting ssl certificate with nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, docker-compose

I want to pass my server in HTTPS with docker nginx image, but it doesn't work, I have create a SSL certificate with openSSL like this on my server:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
```

and I well put the ip adress of my server by answering the questions.

On my server I have a docker-compose.yml which create the nginx container, my docker-compose.yml is like follow:

```
version: "3"
services: 
    nginx: 
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx
        depends_on: 
            - postgres
            - monapp
        volumes: 
            - /home/deployer/util/config/nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
            - /etc/ssl/private:/etc/ssl/private
        network_mode: host
#        ports:
#        - 80:80
#        - 443:443
........
```

volumes with certificates are well passed to  my container (I verified by navigating in the container with docker exec -it nginx bash) and IP adress of my container is the same as my server IP because there is network_mode: host.

My nginx configuration file nginx.conf is :

```
#-------- To redirect to ssl -------     
#server {
#    listen 80;
#    listen [::]:80;
#    server_name 159.65.124.219;
#    location / {
#      proxy_pass http://159.65.124.219:3000;
#    }
#}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 159.65.124.219;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://159.65.124.219:3001/;
      error_log /var/log/front_end_errors.log;
    }
}
```

So I just want that when I go to https://159.65.124.219:443/ it brings me to http://159.65.124.219:3001/ but this is unfortunately not working and I don't know why.... I have search on a lot of forum since more than 1 week.... please help.... Thanks by advance

Comment: Did you create a SSL certificate using the IP address?

Comment: Hi Beppe C ! Yes I used the IP adress 159.65.124.219 and it doesn't work, when I go to https://159.65.124.219:443/ server is loading and never display the page

Comment: Did you verify that the service on http://159.65.124.219:3001/ is actually up and responding with the expected content? If the service running on port 3001 is only listening on `localhost` it won't be accessible on the external IP address - not even for `nginx` running on the same host! If so you may change the `proxy_pass` to `http://localhost:3001` though.

Comment: Hi acran! yes I can access my web app from http, if I go to http://159.65.124.219:3001 I can see my web page, I'm gonna try with localhost !